# Collaboratively Building the Syllabus of a Chess Curriculum

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Is it against the rules of this forum to collaboratively build the syllabus of a chess curriculum?

If not, we need suggestions on how to proceed and we need to add the tag 'curriculum' from now on.

Comment: I think it actually is against the rules. This is not considered a "forum" but a "question and answer website". Your post probably will not be accepted in this form, as it is not really answerable. Some similar question maybe appeared here: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39875/where-can-one-find-a-complete-chess-curriculum/ if you are interested.

Comment: @Christian I was the one who posted the question you mentioned above.
I was looking for a complete curriculum with study material. the three answers were very helpful.
but here I am looking for creating an outline of the  curriculum with resources linked or suggested both free and commercial. 
if I have to form the whole thing as a series of question then let it be.
the final result will be a downloadable pamphlet in some file format.

Comment: Okay, now I feel stupid for not checking the name ;)
I of course cannot know for sure how moderators will treat that but my experience with stackexchange just tells me, that the question might be a bit too loose. To me, what you wrote in this comment already is a bit more defined, i.e. asking for the full Syllabus. Then just the collaboration aspect of course is missing.